# Shopify API connection via Spring framework

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, shopify

Has anyone performed a sucessfull Shopify authentication (and used their APIs) via Spring ?

I have been trying by using the RestTemplate , but can't login :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject("https://apikey:password@shopname.myshopify.com/admin/shop.json",String.class);
    logger.info(result);
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this :

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
```

Whereas it works fine with the browser!

- Do i need to locally import the shopify certificate ? if yes, it has been already done via the keytool.
- Is it possible to authenticate via RestTemplate as I am doing, or should I need to go with Auth0 ?

Feel free to post a working snippet if any of you suceeded :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "xxxxx");
    //headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    String result =  restTemplate.exchange("https://apikey:password@shopname.myshopify.com/admin/shop.json", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
```